# using data-target to add class

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do a simple jQuery function that will add a class using the data target to ad class to the target id. My goal is for the dose to be agnostic to the id so that I don't have to write the code for every id. I am not sure how to write it correctly but I was thinking something like this.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    if([data-target] == (li.id)){
           $(li).addClass(Completed);
    }
  });
```

just a basic match and if match add class

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data

Answer (score 0):

This was the solutions.

```
$(".save").click(function () {
   if ( $("button").data("target") === $("li").data("id")) {  
       var  targetID= $(this).data("target");
       $("#links").find('li[id="' + targetID + '"]').addClass('Completed');
   } else{
   }
 });
```